# How to set the physics size of a circle Phaser Arcade mode

Tags: javascript, html, game-physics, phaser-framework

Using [Phaser](http://phaser.io) I created a game in "Arcade Mode". The game has a snowball, and I need to set the physics size to a sprite that is not like a square (i.e. a circle). How do I do that?

`setSize` doesn't have radius property:

```
setSize(width, height, offsetX, offsetY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Phaser's Arcade physics system is based upon bounding rectangles. If you want to use the Arcade physics system for your game, then you'll need to represent your snowball as a rectangular object in the system (which doesn't need to be the same size as the sprite; it could be a smaller size within).

If you want to use a circular size then you'll have to look at one of the other physics systems that Phaser supports. In your case `P2` is probably what you're looking for.

See [the official Phaser example 'Collide Custom Bounds'](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/p2-physics/collide-custom-bounds) for an example of using a circle to define bounds in P2.

It effectively involves adding P2 physics to the object, or group the object is in, and then using something like `snowball.body.setCircle(16);`

Comment: This is not true in Phaser 3. Arcade physics can have rectangles and circles.

Comment: @EthanMick this question and answer was about Phaser 2. You should definitely create an answer for Phaser 3. :)